# Keep SVG icon along with the next word

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

There is a text paragraph within which several words are grouped into an `inline-div` with a background. To the beginning of this div an SVG-icon is attached:
[see the proto picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF5Qb.jpg).

When the screen resolution is reduced, the icon should be transferred along with the next word.

**Possible solutions and why they are not suitable:**

1. Write the icon into an `inline-div::before` – no way, because the content of this SVG element is animated via `@keyframes`;
2. Do `margin-left` for the `inline-div` and move the icon using `position:absolute` – for Firefox works fine, but not for Chrome;
3. Remove all spaces between the SVG and the next word in the code – I have made one continuous HTML line without spaces and line breaks, the behavior has not changed;
4. `&nbsp;` – after removing the spaces, no longer makes sense to try it, but I have inserted this symbol between the SVG and the `inline-div`, it didn`t work out as well;
5. Do `white-space:nowrap` for the entire `inline-div` – obviously no, because this is made up of several words. It is inside plain text and should behave like plain text.

**Upd**: reproduced codepen https://codepen.io/Hawk1638/pen/XWBXPWV

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.voice {
  display: inline;
}

.voice-content {
  display: inline;
  background: #8f8;
}


/* ANIMATION */

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar {
  transform: scale(1, -1) translate(0, -25px);
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--1 {
  animation: .62s linear 0s short-eq infinite;
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--2 {
  animation: .55s linear .15s tall-eq infinite;
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--3 {
  animation: .45s linear .30s short-eq infinite;
}

@keyframes short-eq {
  0% {
    height: 8px
  }
  50% {
    height: 14px
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px
  }
}

@keyframes tall-eq {
  0% {
    height: 18px
  }
  50% {
    height: 10px
  }
  100% {
    height: 18px
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
  <div class="voice">
    <svg class="eq-bar-wrapper me-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 14 18">
        <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--1" x="0" y="4" width="4" height="10"/>
        <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--2" x="5" y="4" width="4" height="18"/>
        <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--3" x="10" y="4" width="4" height="8"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="voice-content">irure dolor in reprehenderit</div>
  </div> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post up your HTML and CSS too please?

Comment: If I read you correctly, this should do it `.voice { display: inline-block }`. Also, dont use `* { font-size: 1.5rem }` as you will change it for `html` too, the root for `rem`. Just do `body { font-size: 2.25rem }` if you have to, the rest will follow as they inherit by default from `body`. Leave your root font-size default, you will probably need it for all kinds of size settings.

Comment: @RenevanderLende this works in the same way as inline-flex - it wraps to a new line the entire `.inline-div`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Cj2.jpg Thank you for the font-size note. That codepen was just a quick reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the first word together with the icon in a `<span style="display: inline-block">`. You have to combine that with a margin on the outer `.voice` class and absolute positioning of the `<svg>`. This works both in Firefox and Chrome.

```css
.resize {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.voice {
  display: inline;
  background: #8f8;
  margin-left: 1.25em;
  background: #8f8;
}

.first-word {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.eq-bar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}


/* ANIMATION */

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar {
  transform: scale(1, -1) translate(0, -25px);
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--1 {
  animation: .62s linear 0s short-eq infinite;
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--2 {
  animation: .55s linear .15s tall-eq infinite;
}

.eq-bar-wrapper .eq-bar--3 {
  animation: .45s linear .30s short-eq infinite;
}

@keyframes short-eq {
  0% {
    height: 8px
  }
  50% {
    height: 14px
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px
  }
}

@keyframes tall-eq {
  0% {
    height: 18px
  }
  50% {
    height: 10px
  }
  100% {
    height: 18px
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="resize">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    <span class="voice"><span class="first-word">
      <svg class="eq-bar-wrapper me-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 14 18">
          <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--1" x="0" y="4" width="4" height="10"/>
          <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--2" x="5" y="4" width="4" height="18"/>
          <rect class="eq-bar eq-bar--3" x="10" y="4" width="4" height="8"/>
      </svg>
    irure</span> dolor in reprehenderit</span>
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, but if the content is dynamic (which is my case), I have to cut the first word. This is really painful thing, because the first word can be looking like:
<u class="foo">w</u>o<b class="bar">r</b>d

Comment: Moreover, in this case I have to handle punctuation marks, that should remain with the word (such as "-", "!", "?", ",", ".", etc)

Comment: BUT I have investigated further and found out that it's also possible to cut the first letter only. I mean, that <span>w</span><span>ord</span> will never get a break as well. So no need to split words, handle punctuation marks, etc. Just cut the first letter.

Comment: Are you sure about this? A quick test in Firefox just failed for me.

Comment: Eventually this is how I got the desired result: https://codepen.io/Hawk1638/pen/BaPZaBg

Comment: In my app using querySelector I go to the deepest tag, grab the first letter and replace it with a block [icon+letter], so the final html is represented in the codepen. That's it!

Comment: In Firefox, for me the icon moves out to the left of the block if it starts a new line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY0oe.png

Comment: Fixed the codepen. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a solution ?

```
.inline-div {
  display: flex;
}

.inline-div svg {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Comment: If you make it flex, it immediately wraps to a new line.

Comment: Also, if you make it inline-flex, it wraps to a new line the entire `.inline-div`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Cj2.jpg